# How to set a default tensor as a Keras model input?

Tags: keras, input, default

I have a Keras model with multiple images as inputs, but after trained, I'd like to set some images as default input and let just a single placeholder/input as the Query image.

I tried to use `layers.Input(tensor=my_default_tensor)` but it doesn't seems to be what I need, the model still seems to need this input to be given during inference time. I'd like it to be hidden from the user, so he just needs to pass the query image as input.

Comment: Keras does not have this functionality, it  should be implemented at the application level, not as part of a DL framework.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `tf.keras.layers.Input(tensor=tftensor, shape=())?`

Comment: Yes, I did. I discovered this function argument isn't made for this. It just wraps the tensor shape and type to be the same configuration of the `layers.Input()`

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that it is so easy that's why I couldn't find an answer while googling hahaha

It just needed to wrap my "default input images" as a `tf.constant(input_image)`, so I could now use them as normal Keras inputs, but without the need to pass it as a Model input.

Usage example:

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model


image_1 = cv2.imread("image/path/1.jpg")
image_2 = cv2.imread("image/path/2.jpg")

normal_input = layers.Input((256, 256, 3))
default_input_1 = tf.constant(image_1)
default_input_2 = tf.constant(image_2)

x_1 = embeddingModule(default_input_1)
x_2 = embeddingModule(default_input_2)
x_3 = embeddingModule(normal_input)

concat_x1_x3 = layers.Concatenate()([x_1, x_3])
concat_x2_x3 = layers.Concatenate()([x_2, x_3])

relation_1 = relationModule(concat_x1_x3)
relation_2 = relationModule(concat_x2_x3)    

model = Model(inputs=[normal_input], outputs=[relation_1, relation_2])
```

Here, `embeddingModule` and `relationModule` are two pre-trained Keras models.